# Restrict Access to AWS Workspaces to VPN Only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

We have workspaces configured with simple AD / VPC with multiple subnets and also have VPN configured for access to our VPC. I am wondering how to restrict access to user Workspaces / clients to only when they are logged into the VPN. Looking at the documentation and testing, it looks like the workspaces clients go over the workspaces gateways and not over the VPN connection that is established. Do you know if there is a way to restrict this access so only connections from the VPN VPC subnet are allowed to the desktops? We are doing this to limit access / enforce MFA requirements for the environment.

Thanks
Nick